# Cortex M7 random system freezes disconnects debugger

Tags: c++, debugging, freeze, cortex-m, stm32f7

i am developing a pretty complex software for the STM32F746NG. I am using a modded Discovery Board. ST-Link is removed and replaced by a Segger J-Link via JTAG. The Rocktech Display was replaced by a bigger one. And i am using gcc6.2

The system is running pretty well. Except there are some system freezes. It appears randomly while refreshing the Display.

If the freeze happens the debugger cant halt the cpu and connecting the debugger to the cpu is impossible. A LED triggered toggeling by hardware timer stops. And the sending of error messages via UART in the Fault Handler doesent happen. It seems like the CPU just stops and isnt doing anything anymore.

Has anyone an idea what could cause this?

I cannot give the whole code, maybe some snippets.

edit:
It seems like the hardware is alright. New Board with the same 800*480 Display but again with the crappy onboard ST-Link causes the issue again.

Some more information:

- I am using FreeRTOS v9.0.0, there are about 16 tasks running.
- The Tickrate is with 10 kHz relative high but reducing it to 1 kHz didnt resolve the issue.
- The Framebuffer is in the external sdram from the discovery board 2 Framebuffers for Foreground and 1 Framebuffer for background
  last 2 MB are used for heap.

  caddr_t _sbrk(int incr)
  {
      extern char _end; /* Defined by the linker */
      static char *heap_end=0;

  ```
  char *prev_heap_end;

  if (heap_end == 0)
  {
      heap_end = &_end;
  }
  prev_heap_end = heap_end;
  if((uint32_t)heap_end <= _heap1_end)
  {
      if ((uint32_t)heap_end + incr > _heap1_end)
      {
          heap_end = &_endFrameBuffer;
          #ifdef DEBUGMODE
          sendErrToUart("Heap1 is Full: continue at");
          char buff[12];
          sprintf(buff,"%.8x",&_endFrameBuffer);
          sendErrToUart(buff);
          #endif
      }
  }
  else
  {
      if ((uint32_t)heap_end + incr > _RAM2_end)
      {
          #ifdef DEBUGMODE
          sendErrToUart("Heap is Full: exit");
          #endif
          abort ();
      }
  }
  heap_end += incr;
  return (caddr_t) prev_heap_end;
  ```

  }
- malloc is thread save via vTaskSuspendAll();
- HardFault, NMI, BusFault, MemFault and UsageFault Handlers are implemented remove all code from them doesnt resolve the issue

The system freeze always happens while redrawing a Framebuffer (doesnt matter which one) via the function void refreshDisplay();

I observed three different behaviors for the likelihood of the issue.

1. If I call vTaskSuspendAll(); on entry of refreshDisplay and xTaskResumeAll(); on exit the issue is very unlikely. It doesnt happen for hours.
2. If I deactivate all non maskable interrupts i.e. all but reset and nmi ( but they should never be called). I couldn't ever observe the issue in this case.
3. If i deactivate all interrupts with configurable priority i.e. all but reset, nmi and HardFaultHandler. Then the issue is very likely. It happens after some Minutes.

All other configurations are behaving like the last case.

Comment: Does it freeze when running without the debugger?

Comment: yeah it does. But recent tests suggests the problem is a damaged chip. I can say it for sure in about 3 weeks when new hardware arrived.

Comment: I suspect some memory is getting seriously corrupted. Might be a damaged chip but I suspect not.